# How to store superscript in mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql, character

I want to store superscript text in `mysql (sqlyog)`. So is it possible?how?
I added  `'Game™'` text but it displays `'Gameâ„¢'` in `mysql` table. Its `html` output is perfect becuase I used

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Answer (score 1):

Before inserting the values you should run this 
`"SET NAMES utf8"` to store special characters.

Comment: Are your sure about that?can you show me the insert query so that we can see what is exactly there?

Comment: insert into popup_messages set popup_message='Game™'

Comment: How did you check your database character set?

Comment: I must say you should try that query once and check, there are several cases when the table charset is set to latin by default